# Unset primary keys in Entity Framework Core 2

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using integer primary keys for my models that are stored in a database by Entity Framework Core 2. I need to check if the primary key of a model is the final value assigned by Entity Framework or if it hasn't been assigned yet. I haven't found documentation on the exact values used for this, so I'd like to have my guesses confirmed:

- It looks like primary keys start at 1 and are never 0 in the database.
- As the default value of an integer is 0, I can safely assume that if a key is 0 it is unset.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where and why would you need that information. But EF Core provides out of the box two useful methods for that.

First is [EntityEntry.IsKeySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.iskeyset?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_EntityEntry_IsKeySet) property:

> Gets a value indicating if the key values of this entity have been assigned a value.
>
> For keys with store-generated properties (e.g. mapping to Identity columns), the return value will be false if any of the store-generated properties have the CLR default value.
>
> For keys without any store-generated properties, the return value will always be true since any value is considered a valid key value.

While this basically is the same logic as in your assumption, it's better to use it when possible instead of your own hardcoded logic:

```
context.Entry(entity).IsKeySet
```

The second is [PropertyEntry.IsTemporary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyentry.istemporary?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_PropertyEntry_IsTemporary) property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the value of this property is considered a temporary value which will be replaced by a value generated from the store when `SaveChanges()` is called.

For instance, EF Core generates temporary values for identity columns before entities are inserted in the database, and replaces them with the actual values after that. You can use this property if you need to know if the value is final.

```
context.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.Id).IsTemprorary
```

Comment: The reason I want to have this information is that I want models from different DbContext instances to be comparable with Equals() and GetHashCode(). I'm using the primary key for this, but this doesn't work if the primary key is unset / the default value. The methods you pointed are won't work for me, as the model doesn't know about EntityFramework's entities.

Comment: Well, you didn't put such constraints in your question. Anyway, then simply use your assumption (as pointed out in the answer, the documentation of `IsKeySet` property confirms it). Also you can use check for negative values indicating temporary keys. But note that temporary keys will be different in different db contexts, so the technique is unreliable. The first assumption should hold though.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation!